# How to run a script on each folder in a drive?

Tags: python, duplicates, data-cleaning

I am working on a data cleanup in a network drive. The drive has 1000+ folders, and those folders have several subfolders. The script that I got from G4G (seen below) prompts me to select a folder. I can click on one of my 1000+ folders, and the data is cleaned up properly (duplicates are deleted). However, I'd like to loop the command through the whole drive to avoid clicking on folders for hours. I cannot select the drive as my folder because duplicate file names between the first folders in the drive should not be considered duplicates.

Example:
`Z:/Folder1` and `Z:/Folder2` both have several files named `text.txt`, immediately inside of the folders and within the subdirectories of the folders. `Folder1` and `Folder2`, among all `text.txt` files immediately inside and within its subdirectories, should each be left with one `text.txt`. If the current script is applied to `Folder1` and `Folder2` individually, then the desired result of one `text.txt` file existing in `Folder1` and one existing in `Folder2` is accomplished. If the script is applied to the `Z:` drive, then between `Folder1` and `Folder2`, there would only be one `text.txt`, and one of the folders would be without a file named `text.txt`.

How can I apply this script to each first folder in the drive without having to manually click on each folder?

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

# Importing required libraries.
from tkinter import Tk
import os
import hashlib
from pathlib import Path

# We don't want the GUI window of
# tkinter to be appearing on our screen
Tk().withdraw()

# Dialog box for selecting a folder.
file_path = askdirectory(title="Select a folder")

# Listing out all the files
# inside our root folder.
list_of_files = os.walk(file_path)

# In order to detect the duplicate
# files we are going to define an empty dictionary.
unique_files = dict()

for root, folders, files in list_of_files:

    # Running a for loop on all the files
    for file in files:

        # Finding complete file path
        file_path = Path(os.path.join(root, file))

        # Converting all the content of
        # our file into md5 hash.
        Hash_file = hashlib.md5(open(file_path, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()

        # If file hash has already #
        # been added we'll simply delete that file
        if Hash_file not in unique_files:
            unique_files[Hash_file] = file_path
        else:
            if file.endswith((".txt",".bmp")):
                os.remove(file_path)
                print(f"{file_path} has been deleted")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the script as below.
Basically below script gets absolute path of all the directories in the current directory, and feeds them one by one for cleanup.

```py
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

# Importing required libraries.
from tkinter import Tk
import os
import hashlib
from pathlib import Path

# We don't want the GUI window of
# tkinter to be appearing on our screen
Tk().withdraw()

# Dialog box for selecting a folder.
file_paths = [os.path.abspath(i) for i in os.listdir() if os.path.isdir(i)]

for file_path in file_paths:
    # Listing out all the files
    # inside our root folder.
    list_of_files = os.walk(file_path)

    # In order to detect the duplicate
    # files we are going to define an empty dictionary.
    unique_files = dict()

    for root, folders, files in list_of_files:

        # Running a for loop on all the files
        for file in files:

            # Finding complete file path
            file_path = Path(os.path.join(root, file))

            # Converting all the content of
            # our file into md5 hash.
            Hash_file = hashlib.md5(open(file_path, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()

            # If file hash has already #
            # been added we'll simply delete that file
            if Hash_file not in unique_files:
                unique_files[Hash_file] = file_path
            else:
                if file.endswith((".txt",".bmp")):
                    os.remove(file_path)
                    print(f"{file_path} has been deleted")
```